# Getting the operands in an LLVM Instruction

Tags: llvm

I am writing an optimization for my compiler and I use LLVM IR as my Intermediate Language. I have parsed the input file and converted it to LLVM IR. During optimization, I need to retrieve the operands of the instructions. I am able to find `getOpCode()` in the `Instruction` class, but unable to retrieve the operand list. How do I go about that?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There are lots of operand accessors, usually provided by the class `llvm::User`, whose doxygen page is: http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1User.html There's `getNumOperands()` and `getOperand(unsigned int)`, as well as iterator-style accessors `op_begin()` and `op_end()`.

For example, given Instruction `%X = add i32 %a, 2`, `I->getOperand(0)` will return the `Value*` for `%a`, and `I->getOperand(1)` will return the `Value*` for `i32 2` (castable to ConstantInt).

Comment: How do I get `%X`?

Comment: I've found that it really depends on the type. For MachineInstrunctions it seems that zeroth operand is the return value, while arguments start from 1. For regular instruction it looks like the Instruction itself is the return type (can be casted to Value*). Not 100% sure though, this part is not really documented and I couldn't find any good info on it (apart from this SO question).

Answer (score 5):

For instance, if you have `Instruction* I1`, `I1->getOperand(0)` will return the first operand of type `Value*`. You can go further, using `I1->getOperand(0)->getName()` that will return the name of the operand. See `Value` class methods.